# printing to a network printer using fstream c++ in mac

Tags: c++, macos

I wish to print some text directly to a network printer from my c++ code (I am coding with xcode 4). I do know that everything on unix is a file and believe that it would not be impossible to redirect the text using fstream method in c++ to the printer device file. The only problem is I don't know the device file in /dev associated with my network printer.

1. Is it possible to achieve printing using fstream method? Something like

   ```
   std::fstream printFile;
   printFile.open("//PATH/TO/PRINTER/DEV", std::ios::out);

   printFile << "This must go to printer" << std::endl;
   printFile.close();
   ```

   And, if so
2. How to obtain the file in /dev corresponding to a particular printer?

Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

Comment: Seems like for the first part, you could just try it and find out. *Manually* determine the device name and hard-code it into your test program just to see whether you can print that way at all. If that succeeds, *then* ask about how to programmatically determine the device name.

Answer (score 0):

Opening and writing directly to a file used to be possible back in the days of serial printers; however, this is not the approach available today.

The [CUPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS) daemon provides print queuing, scheduling, and administrative interfaces on OS X and many other Unix systems. You can use the `lp(1)` or `lpr(1)` commands to print files. (The different commands come from different versions of print spoolers available in Unix systems over the years; one was derived from the BSD-sources and the other derived from the AT&T sources. For compatibility, CUPS provides both programs.)

You can probably achieve something like you were after with `popen(3)`. In shell, it'd be something like:

```
echo hello | lp -
```

The `-` says to print from standard input.

I haven't tested this, but the `popen(3)` equivalent would probably look like this:

```
FILE *f = popen("lp -", "w");
if (!f)
    exit(1);
fprintf(f, "output to the printer");
```

I recommend testing some inputs at the shell first to make sure that CUPS is prepared to handle the formatting of the content you intend to send. You might need to terminate lines with CRLF rather than just `\n`, otherwise the printer may "stair-step" the output. Or, if you're sending PDF or PS or PCL data, it'd be worthwhile testing that in the cheapest possible manner to make sure the print system works as you expect.

Comment: @Samold: Thanks a lot for your response. I have already tried with popen(). And that works too. What I am concerned about is that (1) popen is a system call, which can slow my code, (2) it is better to know a c++-like way of handling such things, as I will have to read from other devices too, in near future.
Thanks again :)

Comment: Note that opening a file _also_ uses system calls. Where `popen(3)` might be slow is that it _also_ starts `sh -c` to execute the `lp` or `lpr` program. On my Linux system I'm able to start over 1000 copies of `sh -c` per second. Timing `lp` or `lpr` would be a little more difficult, since there's a lot more state there, but I expect that you can submit print jobs a few thousand times faster than your printer can handle the jobs. [Wikipedia claims 200 pages per minute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_printer) for nice laser printers; just how fast _is_ your printer? :)